# Is 'honey in crystallized form' the same as 'raw honey'?

Tags: temperature, honey

Is 'honey in crystallized form' the same as 'raw honey'?

Subquestion: can heated/pasteurized/decrystallized honey ever crystallize again?

Comment: What is your criteria for "equal"? By weight, by volume, by sweetness?

Comment: @CosCallis I took it to mean "are they the same thing"

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer? Maybe. Crystallized honey and raw honey are not mutually exclusive, so you may have a honey that is one or the other, or you may have a honey that is both.

[Raw honey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#Classification_by_packaging_and_processing) is simply honey that has not been over-heated (heated more than necessary to allow the honey to flow for easier bottling) or pasteurized.

[All honey will eventually crystallize](https://www.benefits-of-honey.com/crystallization-of-honey.html); however, raw honey will crystallize faster than pasteurized or heat-treated honey, which is often of lower quality as the heat required for pasteurization destroys some characteristics of the honey.